# Non-proper surjective holomorphic map from the unit disk to itself

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the open unit disk of the complex plane. Does there exist a  non-proper surjective holomorphic map $f \colon \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$? In other words, does every surjective holomorphic map $f \colon \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ satisfy $\lim\limits_{\lvert z \rvert \rightarrow 1} \lvert f(z) \rvert = 1$?

Comment: Corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Using the fact that $f$ is proper iff $f$ is a (ramified) covering, the question is equivalent to find a surjective holomorphic map which is not a ramified covering... Don't know if it helps.

Comment: The proper holomorphic maps $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ are exactly the finite Blaschke products. Therefore, my question is equivalent to asking whether every surjective holomorphic map $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is a finite Blaschke product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counter-example:

Let $g$ be a conformal map from the unit disk $\Bbb D$ to the semi-disk 
$$
 G = \{ z : |z| < 1, \operatorname{Im}(z) > 0 \}
$$
which exists according to the Riemann mapping theorem, and has a continuous one-to-one extension to the closed disk ([Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping))). It is not difficult to find an explicit expression for this mapping, but that is not needed here.

Now let $f(z) = g(z)^3$. $f$ is a surjective mapping from the unit disk onto itself, but for $z \to g^{-1}(\frac 12) \in \partial \Bbb D$ we have $f(z) \to \frac 18 \notin \partial \Bbb D$ .